# Running Docker containers on a chrome extension

Tags: docker, google-chrome-extension, docker-container

I'm coding a chrome extensions (mostly HTML, CSS and JS) and I need an application (that runs on Linux) to connect to the internet and feed some data to the extension's JS scripts. On my machine I'm able to setup and run the app in a Docker container smoothly and I'm wondering whether it's possible to incorporate this container into the chrome extension.

Comment: You can very easily use `docker run` to compromise the entire host, and generally mainstream browsers try to avoid that possibility.  I'd expect it's not possible.

Comment: Depends on what "incorporate" means. Anyway the only method to run external code is [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).